# Update Gutenberg block content before savePost runs

Tags: javascript, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm building a Gutenberg Block and when saving/Publishing posts I need to first save some block data with an API and then update the block attributes with a returned ID from the API and finally save the Post in Wordpress.

Currently I'm using the below hack to take over the Publish button, but I'd like a better solution.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery(".editor-post-publish-button").click(function (event) {
        // Send some requests to an API which returns an ID

        // Update the post with new values

        dispatch('core/block-editor').updateBlockAttributes(clientId, data);

        // Finally save the Post
        dispatch('core/editor').savePost();
        })
    });
}, 3000);
```

Before this solution I tried using subscribe() and checking for events like isSavingPost without success. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: hello, did you find a better solution?

Comment: Also looking for this, would like to generate/get an ID and update a blocks attributes (with the ID) before the save is actually sent...